# Writing JSON using SBJSON

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have recently started parsing JSON documents using SBJSON Parser, and I am able to read JSON documents just fine. However I am unable to figure out how I am meant to write JSON using this library. Under the documentation

http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/interfaceSBJsonStreamWriter.html

There is a class for writing JSON, but I cannot figure out how to use it. There are no tutorials in his documentation on how to use it, and I can't find any tutorials online about using it.

As an example, I tried doing something like this

```
SBJsonStreamWriter *write = [[SBJsonStreamWriter alloc]init];
[write writeObjectOpen];
[write writeString:@"Testing"];
[write writeObjectClose];
```

But I don't know how to print this out, and I need to be able to write JSON for my project as I will be updating JSON files, so need to understand how to write JSON.

As anyone used this library before to write? If so could you please show me a quick example of how it is done

Thanks in advance!

Note: I can't use the in built JSON Parser released with new xCode as my app must be able to support phones from IOS 4+ and the new Parser won't work on phones that do not have IOS 5 installed

EDIT

Example say I wanted to create a JSON file which consisted of an array of names e.g.

{
    "name":[
            "Elliot Jacobs",
            "Paul",
            "Maria",
            "Richard",
            "Ana"
            ]
    }

EDIT 2:

Example two

{
   "HomeScreen":{
      "Title":{
         "Name":"James Bond",
         "Number":"07789 123 456"
      }
   }
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'writing JSON' so I assume that you need to construct a JSON-formatted string. Are you certain that you must use the stream writer? If not, here's an example with strings:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSDictionary *command = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"string1", @"key1",
                                @"string2", @"key2",
                                nil];
NSString *jsonCommand = [writer stringWithObject:command]; // this string will contain the JSON-encoded command NSDictionary
```

Comment: What I mean is, I need to be able to write some JSON and output it to a file. Your code works perfectly, but quick question, what if I want to create a JSON file using code only. The reason I used JSonStreamWriter is that it has commands such as writeOpenArray and writeCloseArray etc, so I assumed that was the class to use to create a JSON file. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: Well, you can use stringWithObject with many object types ([see detailed description](http://json-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/interfaceSBJsonWriter.html)), so you can encode a container with your strings. For the purposes of your edit - a NSDictionary with key @"name" for a NSArray with strings for the names.

Comment: That seemed to work quite well, final question. If you see my edit 2, the way the JSON is laid out as object within in object, as in HomeScreen first, then title, then within title there are two fields name and number. I want to be able to create a JSON file like that using the writer command. The way you showed me works quite well, but can't figure out how to use that method to create a JSON file like the one shown in my edit 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, for that particular case you have to put a NSDictionary in another NSDictionary as an object for key @"HomeScreen" and so on for the other data structures.