# modifying json data in a local file using SBjson

Tags: objective-c, sbjson

I have recently started Application development on MAC OS 10.6, I am trying to modify a "key/value" pair in a local JSON file on my MAC machine using SBJSON. I have successfully read the value of a key, but I am not able to get that how to modify the value of a key and synchronize this to the JSON file. Lets suppose, I have a following JSON Data int o a local file:

```
{
    "name": {
            "fName":"John",
            "lName":"Doe"
            }
            }
```

And i want to change the value of "fName" to something else, like Robert.

I have tried alot searching about it, but got no clue... Can anyone help me.

I am using SBJSON Framework!

Code:

`NSString *filePath  = @"/Users/dev/Desktop/SQLiteFile/myJSON2.json";`

```
NSData   *myData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"FILE CONTENT : %@", responseString);

SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSDictionary * dictionary = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:NULL];



[dictionary setObject:@"Robert" forKey:@"fName"];

//
// Code for writing this change into the file, which i needed.
//

[jsonParser release];
```

Comment: Could you modify your question to show a bit of code that demonstrates how you converted the JSON data to a NSDictionary (or whatever type you used to extract the "`fName`" value)?  If you can do that, I (or somebody else) may be able to more easily help you to come up with a solution.

Comment: Hi Michael !!! I have added code. In which i am getting the JSON data and converting it into a dictionary, then modifying the dictionary. I want these changes to be affected in my local JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You want a mutable deep copy of your dictionary. Then you'll be able to modify it.

Comment: add some code to show how to do that and I'll upvote this potentially fine answer.

Comment: This has already been answered a thousand times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there any other way i can modify a value corresponding to a key in my JSON file.

Comment: OOOOkay.  You're right about that. For the benefit of Aditya, [here is one question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159738/writing-json-using-sbjson) and [here is another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308674/jsonkit-changing-and-serializing-json-attributes-value) (although this latter one is using a different JSON serializer... same concept, tho!).

Comment: Aditya, you cannot modify something that's not mutable, by definition.

Comment: Ok Cyrille, So you want to say that instead of NSDictionary i should take NSMutableDictionary to make the deep mutable copy of my data. And make change sinto that dictionary. But one question how to commit those change sinto the file ???

Comment: Can you tell me an example code how to get the json data into a mutable copy of dictionary !!! and how to commit these changes into file ???

Comment: Search SO for "mutable deep copy of nsdictionary". Then, to write a NSMutableDictionary to a JSON file, you use the same methods than to write a NSDictionary (the former descends from the latter). I don't know how to do it with SBJson, but with JSONKit it's super simple.